# Can't use libpdf.dll with Visual Studio C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I downloaded libpdf.dll and its dependencies from http://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/downloads/list

Then I copied the dlls into "debug" folder within "bin" folder of project. Then, I added reference to libpdf.dll

When I run sample code:

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"D:\test\pdfs\sample.pdf")) // in file
            {
                var bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                using (var pdf = new LibPdf(bytes))
                {
                    byte[] pngBytes = pdf.GetImage(0, ImageType.PNG); // image type
                    using (var outFile = File.Create(@"D:\test\pdfs\file.png")) // out file
                    {
                        outFile.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the following error:

> A procedure imported by 'libpdf.dll' could not be loaded.
>       Make sure that the file is a valid .Net Framework Assembly.

How do I proceed on solving this error? How do I know which dll it is talking about??

Comment: is it a dll with 32bit or a 64bit native code? have you tried 32bit only of the dll and of you dotnet-project?

Comment: According to the download link: https://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/downloads/detail?name=binaries.zip&can=2&q= , dlls are x86 and my project's build platform says "Active (x86)" so I guess both are 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

[startup Element MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Include the following in your configuration file,

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
</startup>
```

Comment: I already did that. Unfortunately, I get the same error. When I read forums, they tell about putting dll files in output directory. What is the output directory of the project? I put the files in bin folder.

Comment: If you are running in Debug mode your output directory would be bin\Debug if its release mode bin\Release

Comment: Then I guess I have placed my dll files in the right place. How do I diagnose the problem deeper? This is the first time I am playing with dlls. Using Jar files was way easier :-(.

Comment: Well, I am going to try this: https://code.google.com/p/lib-pdf/issues/detail?id=4

Comment: @Robik if you are looking for simple PDF to Image converter i would recommend you to check other open source libraries rather than trying solve the issue with the library(Unless its mandatory to use the current library) you are using now. Check http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking into GhostScript and ImageMagick too. But, my soul won't rest in peace until I solve this problem.

Comment: I could not solve the problem so I switched to ImageMagick with ghost script